# Setting up djangoappengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to setup djangoappengine.  I've cloned the code from git / bitbucket per [here](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#installation) (following a number of links from Google), copied over django-testapp and renamed it for my own application.

But python manage.py runserver runs into this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/djangoappengine/management/commands/runserver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db import connections
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/dbindexer/base.py", line 54, in DatabaseWrapper
    return Wrapper(merged_settings, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/dbindexer/base.py", line 37, in __init__
    super(BaseDatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gimli/sandbox/iAgri/whipple/djangoappengine/db/base.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.ops = DatabaseOperations(self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've google around, the project seems to have errors of this sort over time but none of the solutions seem up-to-date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use the code from bitbucket or the docs from allbuttonspressed!**

They are both old and out of date. The new home for the project is:

**http://django-nonrel.org/**

There, you'll find decent documentation and current download links.

Answer (score 1):

To run [djangoappengine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine) get the following modules & copy in your apps root:

1.[autoload](https://github.com/praekelt/autoload)

2.[dbindexer](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-dbindexer)

3.[djangoappengine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine)

4.[djangotoolbox](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox)

5.django (I think its optional)

You can get the [django-testapp](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-testapp)

Answer (score 0):

The allbuttonspressed docs are pretty old and need to be updated, particularly with respect to install.  Fortunately someone built an installer (which I haven't tried):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-non-relational/Nlkh-zldQ6w